# informatica value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: informatica, data-cleaning

I tried to load a table ADuplicate which is duplicate of Table A using one to one mapping direct mapping in Informatica.

But I got following error: 
"Value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"

I noticed that for C4 column, which is number(15) in both tables, has the problem while loading.

Data which has error in loading are 200000300123 and -1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

My doubt is:

1. This value is available in Source of same precision. Why doesn't it get into target?
2. I changed the Target Column C4 as just Number field I could insert this value manually using TOAD but why couldn't I do the same using Informatica?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Shanmugam

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some transformation between source and target that sets a different precision for this port?  Especially the one before the target?

The data written to the target has higher precision - possibly set higher in some transformation(s) in the middle.  You may test with an expression transformation in the middle to reduce the precision.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking "*Enable high precision*" which is available in "*properties*" tab in session properties.